# Default value is not set for Lookup field (Opportunity)

Tags: visual-workflow

When i invoke a flow through Debug Mode, the Input variables screen is showing up. Also when i embed the flow in Right Header Page, the Opportunity Value is displayed as default value.

But when i invoke the same flow by clicking a button, the Opportunity value is not defaulted.

I have attached the Screen shots below:

```
<apex:page >
<flow:interview name="Custom_PlanV15"/>
</apex:page>
```

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        var flow = component.find("Custom_PlanV15");        
        var inputVariables = [
         {name : "Var_Opportunity", type : "Text", value: component.get('v.recordId')}, 
       ];
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
        flow.startFlow("Custom_PlanV15",inputVariables);
        //flow.startFlow("Custom_PlanV15");
    },
})
```

[image: Opportunity is defaulted here]
[image: I am passing opportunity id to this flow and inspite of that Opportunity value is Blank]
[image: Flow settings for lookup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the idea for default values in the link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007PidAAE I think this is an idea for now.